# Smarty Static Path?

Tags: php, smarty

How to specify the static content in Smarty? 
I have many zip attachement for users to download. How do I specify the filepath in Smarty?

`DOMAIN_NAME/static/x.zip` or ?

Answer (score 1):

If your webapp is available at http://example.com and your zip files are stored in the `static` folder, at the same level of your webapp root then just:

```
<h1>Downloads</h1>
{foreach $zips as $zip}
    <a href="/static/{$zip}">{$zip}</a>
{/foreach}
```

If the zip files are outside the web root then you either move them there or make a symlink.

Comment: thanks! a quick question: will smarty use the module "static" if I access the path example.com/static/a.pdf?

Comment: If you want a url instead of a absolute or relative path use `href="http://example.com/path/to/file.pdf"`. Not sure what you mean by "module".